# Scala: Generic isInstanceOf based on sealed hierarchy

Tags: scala

I'm trying to generalize some sort of `isIntanceOf` based on a sealed hierarchy, but haven't been successful. The example below demonstrates what I want to achieve:

```
  sealed abstract class Context

  object Context {
    case object Context1 extends Context

    case class Context2(someInfo: String) extends Context

    case object Context3 extends Context
  }

  case class ContextHolder(id: String, contexts: Set[Context])

  import Context._
  val holder = ContextHolder("1", Set(Context1, Context2("Other info")))

  val contains1Or2 = holder.contexts.contains(Context1) || holder.contexts.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Context2])
  val contains3    = holder.contexts.contains(Context3)

  println(s"contains1Or2: $contains1Or2")
  println(s"contains3: $contains3")
```

Basically I want to generalize the code of `contains1Or2` and `contains3` in some sort of:

```
def containsAnyOf[T <: Context: ClassTag](holder: ContextHolder, contexts: T*): Boolean
```

And then be able to use it like:

```
    val contains1Or2 = containsAnyOf(holder, Context1, Context2)
    val contains3    = containsAnyOf(holder, Context3)
```

I've already tried a few different approaches, but couldn't get it to work so far. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Shapeless has a type class `LiftAll` that you may find helpful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I could come up was this:

```scala
def containsAnyOf(holder: ContextHolder)(contexts: PartialFunction[Context, Unit]): Boolean = {
  val p = contexts.lift.andThen(_.isDefined)
  holder.contexts.exists(p)
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```scala
val contains1Or2 = containsAnyOf(holder) {
  case Context1 =>
  case Context2(_) => // or case _: Contaxt2 =>
}

val contains3 = containsAnyOf(holder) {
  case Context3 =>
}
```

Code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/CYOZYsbmRiuLvmRLQ4nfhg/6).

Comment: you don't have to do `contexts.lift.andThen(...)`, you can simply use `contexts.isDefinedAt`

Answer (score 2):

Shapeless's [`LiftAll`](http://docs.glngn.com/latest/api/com.chuusai.shapeless_2.12/shapeless/ops/coproduct$$LiftAll.html) type class is very handy here.

```scala
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{LiftAll, ToTraversable}
import shapeless.{Generic, HList}

final class ContainsMulti[T <: Product](private val dummy: Boolean = true) extends AnyVal {
  def apply[H <: HList, O <: HList](holder: ContextHolder)(implicit
      toHList: Generic.Aux[T, H],
      classTags: LiftAll.Aux[ClassTag, H, O],
      allCtxts: LiftAll[({type E[T] = T <:< Context})#E, H],
      toList: ToTraversable.Aux[O, List, ClassTag[_]]
  ) = classTags.instances.toList
    .map(_.runtimeClass)
    .forall(klazz => holder.contexts.exists(klazz.isInstance))
}

def containsMulti[T <: Product] = new ContainsMulti[T]
```

Usage:

```scala
val contains1Or2 = containsMulti[(Context1.type, Context2)](holder)
val contains3 = containsMulti[Tuple1[Context3.type]](holder)
val contains1and3 = containsMulti[(Context1.type, Context3.type)](holder)
val check = containsMulti[(Int, String)](holder) //doesn't compile

println(s"contains1Or2: $contains1Or2")  //true
println(s"contains3: $contains3")        //false
println(s"contains1and3: $contains1and3")//false
```

[See it run](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/coGFjb5QSkiHxNWdXbPnsQ).

All the implicits may seem daunting, but it's actually very simple. The extra class is so we can take multiple type parameter lists, where the first is explicitly given, and the second is inferred. `Generic` turns the inputted tuple into an `HList`, `LiftAll` finds the `ClassTag` instances for each of the types in the tuple, and `ToTraversable` turns the `HList` containing those class tags back into a `List`.

As Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817749/scala-generic-isinstanceof-based-on-sealed-hierarchy#comment116372153_65818432), I have made `ContainsMulti` a value class, using the partially applied type trick to avoid object creation. They also pointed out that this approach initially allowed `(Int, String)` as input, so now `allCtxts` checks that all the types in the HList extend `Context`.